# In VBA is it possible to find the last value in a seriescollection?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Series_Values()

Dim Cht As Chart

For Each Cht In ActiveWorkbook.Charts

    
    For i = 1 To Cht.SeriesCollection.Count
        Debug.Print Cht.SeriesCollection(i).Name
        Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Max(Cht.SeriesCollection(i).Values)
        Debug.Print Cht.SeriesCollection(i).Points.Count
        Debug.Print Cht.SeriesCollection(i).Values(Points.Count)
    Next i

Next Cht

End Sub
```

For my case the max is often the right answer. But I'd prefer to find the last Y value in the series. The Values(Points.Count) code will not work.

Answer (score 1):

- Your code is close. Assign `.Value` to an array, then retrieve the last item.

```vb
Sub Series_Values()
    Dim Cht As Chart, i As Long, aVal
    For Each Cht In ActiveWorkbook.Charts
        For i = 1 To Cht.SeriesCollection.Count
            With Cht.SeriesCollection(i)
                Debug.Print .Name
                Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Max(.Values)
                Debug.Print .Points.Count
                aVal = .Values
                Debug.Print aVal(UBound(aVal)) ' last point
                ' OR
                Debug.Print aVal(.Points.Count) ' last point
            End With
        Next i
    Next Cht
End Sub
```